# Why does my Bazel build always compile repeatly?

Tags: c++, bazel, bazel-rules

In my C++ project, I am really bothered by the problem: that when i run command `bazel build XXX` or `bazel test XXX`, the Bazel process always compile files repeatly, repeatly compile files that i did't change.

How should I check this problem? check my Bazel files or my Bazel cache? i am new to Bazel tools.

the recompile process always start from protobuf files.

i cd to directory `bazel-cache`.
but i don't know how to check it.
and my `BUILD.bazel` file is using `cc_unit_test`.

Comment: Bazel will recompile files based on what you changed and how your project is organized. No one here is a mind reader, so that is the extent that anyone can help you without the actual file content.

Comment: you could start with `--explain`, e.g. `--explain=/tmp/explain.txt`: https://bazel.build/reference/command-line-reference#flag--explain but more information would be helpful